# How to check remote session enabled?

Tags: python, remote-access

If remote access session is enabled, I have to disable and later enable it. How to achieve this using Python code?.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you mean by a remote access session.

To see all listening services / ports run one of the following commands:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
```

If you leave off the `| grep LILSTEN` part the same commands will also show active connections.

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n
sudo netstat -tulpn
```

Typically VNC connections will use ports of 5900 or so.

On my system I see:

```
systemd      1    root   33u  IPv4  17131      0t0  TCP *:111 (LISTEN)
systemd      1    root   41u  IPv6  17133      0t0  TCP *:111 (LISTEN)
cupsd     2071    root    6u  IPv6  43261      0t0  TCP [::1]:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd     2071    root    7u  IPv4  43262      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:631 (LISTEN)
```

So I know everything on that list.

I suppose it is possible for crackers to hide services, but that is a separate discussion.